# Why C# LINQ expressions must end with Select or Group By Clause where as no such restriction in VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

As my title is self explanatory, I know how to rectify it but why is it so in the first place?

**Scenario**

I wrote a VB.Net Code

```
Dim list As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

//Code to populate list

Dim wherelinq As IEnumerable(Of String) = From s In list Where s.StartsWith("A")
```

This works fine and gives no error

but the same logic in C# fails

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

//Code to populate list

IEnumerable<string> wherelinq = from s in list where s.StartsWith("A");
```

This gives error

[image]

Why this restriction in C#? Anything specific that I am missing?

Comment: We need some Eric Lippert here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VB.NET and C# are different languages, so it is natural that the LINQ query syntax is different, too: C# requires `select s`, while VB.NET does not.

Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384065.aspx) requires that a query syntax query in C# must end in `select` or `group`:

> A query expression must begin with a from clause and must end with a select or group clause. Between the first from clause and the last select or group clause, it can contain one or more of these optional clauses: where, orderby, join, let and even additional from clauses. You can also use the into keyword to enable the result of a join or group clause to serve as the source for additional query clauses in the same query expression.

See C# language specification, section 7.16, for details on the syntax.

```
var wherelinq = from s in list where s.StartsWith("A") select s;
```

You do not have to add `select` if you use the function syntax:

```
var wherelinq = list.Where(s => s.StartsWith("A"));
```

Comment: You did not explain why it is like that in C#. Unless there is no explanation other than developers just forgot to include that.

Comment: I already said that I know how to rectify it. But why is it so?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: thanks for the link. I updated your answer with a quote from there - hope you don't mind.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Thanks for it. But thinking from a developer point of view, why is so. Why do they have to maintain 2 different logic. One for C# and other for VB.Net? Anything different in these languages architecture or something? I am sure person like Eric Lippert or Jon Skeet can give an inside view of these languages.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal - If you want my guess, and this could be confirmed by checking the IL, VB.NET is probably adding the Select statement for you. VB often adds implicit language constructs while C# requires the developer to be more explicit. Just two different languages: different developers love each.

Comment: The snarky answer to the question: Because the C# Spec Writers decided that a LINQ should end with select and group. The real question: Why did the Spec writers do so? Only they can answer, I can only make a guess: C# is usually very heavy on explicitness (to avoid many undefined behaviors that plague C++) and allow for very few ambiguities, so it's just consistent.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually called a degenerate select.
You don't need it when you use lambda syntax, which the query is compiled to.
Why this restriction is required, I don't really know. These are probably some compiler related restrictions that really didn't have to be there.

Answer (score -2):

One reason is that without the `select` clause there would be ambiguities.  In the following example, how would the compiler know whether `where false` filters dogs or bones?

```
from dog in dogs
let gifts = from bone in bones
            where false
```

However, half of your question is still unanswered: how does VB avoid such ambiguities?

Comment: Why is this ambigous? VB.NET would select an anonymous type which contains both as properties(`dog` and `bone`).

Answer (score -2):

Despite the fact that in a degenerate select case, `Where()` and `Where().Select()` should return equivalent collections logically, and thus making the `Select()` clause look redundant superficially, the return types may be different. It may be that the return type of `Where()` is not intended for end-use, but for chaining with additional query operations like `Select()`. That is, you may not do anything useful with the return value of `Where()` other than appending a `Select()` operation. By requiring ending with `select` or `group`, C# imposes less requirements on the LINQ provider in the sense that it doesn't require the return value of `Where()` to be suitable for end-use, and this allows greater flexibility in the design of `Where()`.